# Is there a direct link to create and open a new Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I go to https://sheets.google.com and then click on `+` to create and open a new Google Sheet. Is there a direct link to create and open a new Google Sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the direct link is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create It works for me.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks @user2946433. May I know how you 'found' this URL :)?

Comment: When you create a new spreadsheet you will see appear that url on browser for few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

side note: there is also a nice shortcut sequence when you are at any open spreadsheet:

<kbd>**<kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd>** **+** **<kbd>F</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>N</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>** + **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**